# Three distinct numbers between 10 and 25 (inclusive) are chosen at random. What is the probability that the numbers are all composite numbers?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

Three distinct numbers between 10 and 25 (inclusive) are chosen at
random. What is the probability that the numbers are all composite
numbers?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You'll get a lot more help if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself, even if you haven't made much progress. What are your thoughts? What have you tried? How far could you get? Where are you stuck? This question will likely be closed if you don't add more context. Please respond by editing the question body. Clarifications don't belong in the comments.

Comment: By “numbers” you mean integers?

Comment: Are the numbers chosen with or without replacement?

Comment: "Are the numbers chosen with or without replacement?"  ...."Three *distinct* numbers between 10 and 25 (inclusive) are chosen at random"....... "By “numbers” you mean integers? "  and *that* is a valid question (and the assumption "yes" is reasonable, but not certain).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Without replacement,
$$\mathbb{P}\text{ (Numbers chosen are all composite}) = \frac{\text{Number of ways to choose $3$ composite numbers}}{\text{Number of ways to choose any 3 numbers}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Between $10$ to $25$ ($16$ numbers) there are $5$ primes ($11,13,17,19, 23$) and $11$ composite.

So the probability that the first number drawn is composite is $\frac {11}{16}$.

*If* that happens, then there are $10$ remaining composites and $15$ numbers.

So the probability of drawing a composite number after someone has removed a composite is  $\frac {10}{15}=\frac 23$.

And likewise the probability of drawing a composite number after someone has removed two composites are $\frac 9{14}$.

So the probability of all three events are $\frac {11}{16}\cdot \frac {10}{15}\frac {9}{14} = \frac {11\cdot 10 \cdot 9}{16\cdot 15\cdot 14} = \frac {11\cdot 1 \cdot 3}{8\cdot 1\cdot 14} =\frac {33}{112}$

.....

Alternatively.... there are $11P3 = 11\cdot 10 \cdot 9$ ways to chose $3$ composite numbers and there are $16P 3= 16\cdot 15\cdot 14$ ways to choose $3$ numbers, so the probability is $11\cdot 10 \cdot 9$ out of $16\cdot 15\cdot 14$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig  But everyone know $16  - 5 = 9$.  Right?

Comment: Thanks for the dose of levity.